# Tag synonym request: [lexical-analysis] and [lexer]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

The [lexical-analysis](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lexical-analysis) tag was [created in February 2016](/q/6588/9357) and currently has 36 questions.  [lexer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lexer) was created in January 2019 and has 31 questions.  A few questions are tagged with both.

Don't these tags cover the same topic?  What shall we do about the redundancy?

Comment: Is it possible to merge them and just keep the simpler one, `lexer`, re-labelling questions that had `lexical-analysis`?

Comment: I'm not expert in that field, but I'd imagine [tag:lexical-analysis] being (slightly) broader than [tag:lexer] where the broader one would be the one we want to end up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done.

[lexer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lexer) has been synonimized and merged into [lexical-analysis](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lexical-analysis), so the correct tag will automatically show up when searching for it in the Tags section below a new question:

[image: Searching for lexer in Tags section shows lexical-analysis]

Some statistics:

[lexer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lexer) has been removed from 32 questions.
[lexical-analysis](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lexical-analysis) has been added to 29 questions.
This implies 3 questions previously had both tags applied.

[lexical-analysis](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lexical-analysis) now has 65 questions (35 short of being badge worthy).
9 of those are unanswered.